# Loop through each xml result and add in seperate DIVs

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xml

I'm trying to use jQuery and XML to create image thumbnails and captions. I'm able to get the xml data to the page, but how do I make the images and captions load in to separate DIVs?

```
<div id="gDesigns"></div>
```

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "imgs/thumbs/xml/furniture.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
        $(xml).find('designName').each(function(){
            var sTitle = $(this).find('Thumb').text();
            var sPublisher = $(this).find('Code').text();

            $("#gDesigns").append('<div class="tBody" id="' + sTitle + '"> <div class="bImg"> <img src="designs/thumbs/' + sTitle + '.jpg"> <div class="txt">' + sPublisher + '</div> </div> </div>')
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("An error occurred.");
    }
});
```

My question is how do I add each xml result as below

```
<div class="tBody" id="??">
    <div class="bImg">
        <img src="designs/thumbs/??.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="txt">
        Caption
    </div>
</div>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Furniture>
    <designName>
        <Thumb>teakTbl</Thumb>
        <Code>1234</Code>
    </designName>
    <designName>
        <Thumb>mahoganiTbl</Thumb>
        <Code>12345</Code>
    </designName>
    <designName>
        <Thumb>darkTbl</Thumb>
        <Code>97864</Code>
    </designName>
</Furniture>
```

Comment: Your code appears to be doing what you need, why does it not work?

Comment: There is no element in your sample output with id "gDesigns": please ensure your sample code is complete and working so we can see what you have.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: It only shows the first image and caption. I want to display all images + captions.

Comment: Are you sure there are multiple `designName` elements returned in your XML? Can you post your XML response?

Comment: @Richard: `<div id="gDesigns"></div>` is there. I've updated my post.

Comment: Please post response xml

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I've updated my post with my XML.

Comment: Given your XML, your code appears to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/8o3w71o3/